# Install INF on Win8 using RUNDLL32 does nothing

Tags: windows-8, drivers, installation, rundll32.exe, inf

I am trying to install a device driver from the command line using the following:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 .\<driver>_x64.inf
```

Unfortunately nothing seems to be happening. The device continues to show as unknown in the Device Manager.

However, if I go into Windows Explorer, right-click on the .INF file and select "Install", it does install successfully.

So my question is: Why won't the above command line work for me? (I got this from here)

If I got some sort of error dialog appearing, that would helpful but I'm getting nothing at all. What do I need to do to mimic the right-click "Install" behaviour?

I have also tried this on two different machines - both Windows 8.1 - same thing.

Comment: Why is one of your arguments `./_x64.inf` that does not seem right

Comment: @Ramhound: Sorry - I got in trouble for putting this question on StackOverflow so I cut and pasted the content. I've changed the question so it contains the formatting. The _X64.inf is only part of the .INF filename. It should make a bit more sense now - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well now you flipped the **/** to a \ there is a huge difference.